# How to simplify imports in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

My starting code often looked like this:

```
import libs.apa_database
import inspect
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, Property
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
```

So, I wondered if there were a way to reduce the clutter like this:

```
from system_assets import APADatabase, App, Clock 
from layout_assets import App, BoxLayout, GridLayout, ScrollView
from screen_assets import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from interface_assets import DropDow, Button,
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes":

1. Create new Python files as a "folder" to hold your imports
2. Add the import statements to that Python file
3. Import the assets from that file

(Will update this Q with more detail when I have time.)

Comment: Or just `import kivy` then use them like `kivy.X.Y`

Comment: @SimonMengong, **no!** After `import kivy` you may use only *imported names* (for example `kivy.platform`), but not modules like `kivy.clock` or `kivy.properties` – they still require another import (e.g., `import kivy.clock`).